# Parse decimal number without loosing significant digits

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, numbers

I need to parse user input as a number and store it in a [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) variable.

It is important for me to not accept any user input that cannot be properly represented by a [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) value.

This works fine for very large (or very small) numbers, since the [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx(v=vs.110).aspx) method throws an [OverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx) in those cases.

However, when a number has too many significant digits the [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx(v=vs.110).aspx) method will silently return a truncated (or rounded?) value.

For example, parsing `1.23456789123456789123456789123` (30 significant digits) results in a value equal to `1.2345678912345678912345678912` (29 significant digits).

This is according to the [specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that says that a [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) value has a precision of 28-29 significant digits.

However, I need to be able to detect (and reject) numbers that will be truncated when parsed, since loosing significant digits is unacceptable in my case.

What is the best way to go about this?

---

Please notice, that pre-parsing or post-validation by string comparison is not a simple way to go since I need to support all kinds of culture-specific input and all kinds of [number styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (whitespace, thousand separators, parenthesis, exponent syntax, etc).

Therefore, I'm looking for a solution to this without duplicating the parsing code as provided by .NET.

---

I'm currently using this workaround to detect input with 28 or more significant digits. While this works, it effectively limit all input to at most 27 significant digits (instead of 28-29):

```
/// <summary>
///     Determines whether the specified value has 28 or more significant digits, 
///     in which case it must be rejected since it may have been truncated when 
///     we parsed it.
/// </summary>
static bool MayHaveBeenTruncated(decimal value)
{
    const string format = "#.###########################e0";
    string str = value.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return (str.LastIndexOf('e') - str.IndexOf('.')) > 27;
}
```

Comment: You can try converting the decimal to string and comparing with the original.

Comment: @IllidanS4: But that will reject all input that is not formatted according to whatever format that I use to format the decimal value as a string.

Comment: True. You can sacrifice one decimal digit and count the number of digits in the converted string, if it is less than 28 or 29. If so, some digits may have been lost, although it may reject inputs which have 29 significant digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first state that there **is no** "official" solution. Normally I would not rely on internal implementation, so I'm providing you the following just because you said it's very important to you to get that resolved.

If you take a look at the reference source, you'll see that all parse methods are implemented in a (unfortunately internal) [System.Number](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,86404b606ba1649f,references) class. Further investigating, the `decimal` related methods are [TryParseDecimal](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,86404b606ba1649f,references) and [ParseDecimal](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,40cc4c7078ce36d7), and they both use something like this

```
byte* buffer = stackalloc byte[NumberBuffer.NumberBufferBytes];
var number = new NumberBuffer(buffer);
if (TryStringToNumber(s, styles, ref number, numfmt, true))
{
   // other stuff
}
```

where `NumberBuffer` is another internal `struct`. The key point is that the whole parsing happens inside the `TryStringToNumber` method and the result is used to produce the result. What we are interested is a [NumberBuffer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,961cb25f24056f66,references) field called `precision` which is populated by the above method.

With all that in mind, we can generate a similar method just to extract the precision after calling the base decimal method to ensure a normal validation/exceptions before we do our post processing.  So the method would be like this

```
static unsafe bool GetPrecision(string s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
{
    byte* buffer = stackalloc byte[Number.NumberBuffer.NumberBufferBytes];
    var number = new NumberBuffer(buffer);
    TryStringToNumber(s, styles, ref number, numfmt, true);
    return number.precision;
}
```

But remember, those types are internal, as well as their methods, so it's difficult to apply the normal reflection, delegate or `Expression` based techniques. Fortunately, it's not so hard to write such a method using `System.Reflection.Emit`. The full implementation is as follows

```
public static class DecimalUtils
{
    public static decimal ParseExact(string s, NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number, IFormatProvider provider = null)
    {
        // NOTE: Always call base method first 
        var value = decimal.Parse(s, style, provider);
        if (!IsValidPrecision(s, style, provider))
            throw new InvalidCastException(); // TODO: throw appropriate exception
        return value;
    }

    public static bool TryParseExact(string s, out decimal result, NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number, IFormatProvider provider = null)
    {
        // NOTE: Always call base method first 
        return decimal.TryParse(s, style, provider, out result) && !IsValidPrecision(s, style, provider);
    }

    static bool IsValidPrecision(string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        var precision = GetPrecision(s, style, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
        return precision <= 29;
    }

    static readonly Func<string, NumberStyles, NumberFormatInfo, int> GetPrecision = BuildGetPrecisionFunc();
    static Func<string, NumberStyles, NumberFormatInfo, int> BuildGetPrecisionFunc()
    {
        const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        const BindingFlags InstanceFlags = Flags | BindingFlags.Instance;
        const BindingFlags StaticFlags = Flags | BindingFlags.Static;

        var numberType = typeof(decimal).Assembly.GetType("System.Number");
        var numberBufferType = numberType.GetNestedType("NumberBuffer", Flags);

        var method = new DynamicMethod("GetPrecision", typeof(int),
            new[] { typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles), typeof(NumberFormatInfo) },
            typeof(DecimalUtils), true);

        var body = method.GetILGenerator();
        // byte* buffer = stackalloc byte[Number.NumberBuffer.NumberBufferBytes];
        var buffer = body.DeclareLocal(typeof(byte*));
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, numberBufferType.GetField("NumberBufferBytes", StaticFlags));
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Localloc);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, buffer.LocalIndex);
        // var number = new Number.NumberBuffer(buffer);
        var number = body.DeclareLocal(numberBufferType);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, number.LocalIndex);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, buffer.LocalIndex);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Call, numberBufferType.GetConstructor(InstanceFlags, null,
            new[] { typeof(byte*) }, null));
        // Number.TryStringToNumber(value, options, ref number, numfmt, true);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, number.LocalIndex);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Call, numberType.GetMethod("TryStringToNumber", StaticFlags, null,
            new[] { typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles), numberBufferType.MakeByRefType(), typeof(NumberFormatInfo), typeof(bool) }, null));
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
        // return number.precision;
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, number.LocalIndex);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, numberBufferType.GetField("precision", InstanceFlags));
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Func<string, NumberStyles, NumberFormatInfo, int>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, NumberStyles, NumberFormatInfo, int>));
    }
}
```

Use it on your own risk :)

Comment: Excellent work. Thank you! Although, I guess I'll still have to use my `ToString('#.#####...")` workaround to ensure that no significant digit is lost. Your code always test for 29 or less, but decimal has a precision of 29 *or* 28.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the unclear things in the documentation. For instance,  the **Remarks** [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) say "The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28". So probably the check should simply be for 28? I know you are referring to "decimal (C# Reference)", but I've never seen an example of decimal with 29 digits after decimal point, do you? Tried `decimal d = 0.00000000000000000000000000001m;` an got zero.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is a string and it has been validated as numeric, you can use String.Split:

```
text = text.Trim().Replace(",", "");
bool neg = text.Contains("-");
if (neg) text = text.Replace("-", "");
while (text.Substring(0, 1) == 0 && text.Substring(0, 2) != "0." && text != "0")
    text = text.Substring(1);
if (text.Contains("."))
{
    while (text.Substring(text.Length - 1) == "0")
        text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
}
if (text.Split(".")[0].Length + text.Split(".")[1].Length + (neg ? 1 : 0) <= 29)
    valid = true;
```

You could override or replace Parse and include this check.

Comment: This might work for simple input. But does not handle leading/trailing sign/whitespace/zeroes and does not take the exponent syntax into account.

Comment: True, but that can be sorted out in preceding parsing checks. Then have the split values converted back to decimals for use as the OP wishes.

Comment: I'm afraid that this approach would result in quite complex parsing checks (taking into account culture settings, thousand separators, etc). I'm looking for a cleaner solution (if possible),

Comment: Whitespace can be dealt with using Trim() and leading zeroes with a loop, the sign can also be dealt with easily. As for exponent syntax, I don't think it's normal to allow this for data entry, but you can add logic to also deal with that, but I would probably just disallow it.

Comment: I need to accept all number styles in all supported cultures and reject all numbers that cannot be represented as a decimal value.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a few more checks. Hopefully this helps. As for exponents. You could write some logic to translate such formats to a simple decimal format before these checks

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Still this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the rounding is taken care of when you do the conversation i.e. `Decimal myNumber = Decimal.Parse(myInput)` will always return in a rounded number if there are more than 28 decimals.

You don't want to create a big parser either so what I would do is compare the input string value with the new decimal value as a string:

```
//This is the string input from the user
string myInput = "1.23456789123456789123456789123";

//This is the decimal conversation in your application
Decimal myDecimal = Decimal.Parse(myInput);

//This is the check to see if the input string value from the user is the same 
//after we parsed it to a decimal value. Now we need to parse it back to a string to verify
//the two different string values:
if(myInput.CompareTo(myDecimal.ToString()) == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("EQUAL: Have NOT been rounded!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("NOT EQUAL: Have been rounded!");
```

This way C# will handle all the number stuff and you will only do a quick check.

Comment: Thanks, but this would reject all input that is not formatted according to the default decimal string format.

Comment: That can be handled with NumberStyles: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kb11ck8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But then I need to know exactly which style that user have used.

Comment: Could you give some examples on different inputs? 1.1234'1234? 1.1234,1234? The problem I see here is that maybe you should try and work this out on the User Application side i.e. make sure "good data" comes in.

Comment: Or is it sent in by the OS? With the Regional Settings screwing it up?

Comment: Yes. Input may be localized using any supported .NET culture. It may be specified with whitespace, thousand separators, exponents, or any other number style supported by .NET.

Comment: Now it seems to be two different questions (One about comparing two decimal values, which have been answered, and another about CultureInfo). I would probably create a new thread with the title "How to convert a regional string number?". Or maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx can help you? /Sweden out

Comment: No this question is about finding out whether parsing a number will result in a loss of significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [BigRational](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782) impelmentation. It is not (yet?) part of the .Net framework, but it is the aquivalent to the BigInteger class and provides a TryParse method. This way you should be able to compare if your parsed BigRational is equal to the parsed decimal.

Comment: This sure sounds promising. However, I cannot find a `TryParse` implementation except the one provided by `BigInteger`.

Comment: How about the one Transit C# implements: https://github.com/NForza/transit-csharp/blob/master/src/Transit/Numerics/BigRational.cs

Comment: Unfortunately that parse function does not support any of the .NET number styles which is a requirement in my case.